# How can I make a div auto adopt the height left in screen?

Tags: html, css

for example :
I just have two divs in a body, body's height is 100%:

```
<body>
<div id="menuBar" style="height:30px"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

I want #content can auto adopt the height left in browser window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: Why do you want to do this? Normally something like this is not necessary, and you just need to to **look** as if `content` fills the rest of the window, and there are better solutions depending on your actual objective.

Especially the fixed height in pixels of the "menu bar" will be problematic - keep in mind it's not possible to force a specific font size on your user!

If you really **know** that this what you want, then you can position `content` absolutely:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

(However this isn't supported by IE6.)

Comment: (+1) I totally forgot that... ;) However, absolute positioning is not always the way you want to go...

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS, this is not possible. You would need to use Javascript in order to make it fill the entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the window height and subtract the menuBar height. Here is an example with jQuery...

```
$h = $(window).height() - $('#menuBar').height();
$('#content').height($h + 'px');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2ugMV/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple hack, which will give you what you are after.
This just hides 30px of the content under the menu. Then using padding of 30 makes sure the content is in the correct place.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;padding:0px;margin:0px;">

<div id="menu" style="position:relative;height:30px;background-color:#FF0000;z-index:100;"></div>
<div id="content" style="position:relative;height:100%;background-color:#00FF00;margin-top:-30px;z-index:90;padding:30px;">
<p>hello world</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```